# Keep Global Variable value over Modules

Tags: microsoft-excel, global

Good Day

I did create a Global variable in my Script. It does keep the variable itself over Module correctly, but it doesn't keep the contain of the variable. Is there a way to keep its contain?

I've tried with

```
Set ProcessFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

But this line return me an error.

I did try with both Global and Public.

My code :

```
Option Explicit
Global FirstDay As Boolean
Global ProdPreviousFileName  As String
Global WMsgBox As Integer
Global PreviousDate As String
Global PreviousFile As String
Public ProcessFileName As String

Sub Auto_Open()

 ProcessFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'This is the Variable I want to keep the contain
    
Sheets("GENERAL INFORMATION").Select
Range("A1").Select


WMsgBox = MsgBox("Start Compliancy Report Building ?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

If WMsgBox = vbYes Then
    WMsgBox = MsgBox("Is is the first business day of the week ?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If WMsgBox = vbYes Then
        FirstDay = True
        PreviousFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        Title:="Select previous available Compliancy Report")
    Call Module1.DEFINE_PROD_VARIABLES

    Else
    FirstDay = False
        PreviousFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        Title:="Select previous available Compliancy Report")
    Call Module1.DEFINE_PROD_VARIABLES
    End If
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you declared the variable as `Global`? Please show us some code.

Comment: Yes I did try with Both Global and Public

Comment: Try assigning `ThisWorkbook.variable`. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27578082/165358).

Comment: I finally find my problem. The Global Variable was actually Dimmed at the beginning of another Module, so basically reset the value. All working well now. Thanks